# My.Resources and My.Computer giving error when using embedded files

Tags: vb.net

Clicking a button in a Windows Form to load `My.Resources` using embedded files under `Resources` has started to give me the following error:

> NEDeWFMNewHireList' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules 'CCOPS.My.Resources.Resources' and 'CCOPS.My.Resources.Resources'.   D:\CCOPS Toolbox\CCOPSToolboxCodeForm.vb.

I have been using these commands for a total of 15+ .msg, .exe files without issues, but now I am getting this error message.

Exact code sample below:

```vb
Private Sub Button93_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button93.Click
    IO.File.WriteAllBytes(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\NEDeWFMNewHireList.msg", My.Resources.NEDeWFMNewHireList)
    Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\NEDeWFMNewHireList.msg")
End Sub
```

Comment: I am finding that my project folder is creating new Resources.Designer.vb files each time I load Visual Studios Project associated with this Windows Form.  This is what is causing the error but it will not stop doing it and causing more issues.

Comment: Resolved by cleaning up duplicates in the Project folder.